# mysql :ordering table with day names

Tags: mysql, dayofweek

I am trying to get day of names with and correct order like  Monday ,Tuesday.. But  in my table I have records that after  Monday comes Friday  or  I have Thursday between  two Tuesday .I want to order them like Monday ,Monday ,Tuesday ,Tuesday, Wednesday so on .But I don`t want to group them.

I used this query but it does not make order

```
select Day_Name from mydb.schedule where Room_NO=(510) And Week_NO =(1)
```

it outputs

```
Monday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Thursday
Thursday
Thursday
```

how can I correct it?

Comment: Why are you storing the day name instead of the day index?

Comment: because those day names are string.They have no index

Answer (score 2):

if you actually store the date as a column, you can use the datepart of it...  if not, you might need to use a case

```
case 
   when day_name = "Monday" then 1
   when day_name = "Tuesday" then 2
   when day_name ...
...
..
end as SortBySequence
```

Comment: where must i have use this case? It gave syntax error. I used like 
select Day_Name from mydb.schedule where Room_NO=(510) And Week_NO =(1) case when ....

Answer (score 1):

Change 'day_name' column type to ENUM ('Monday',...,'Sunday'), then sort query by it. ENUM should do the trick.